# Cannot connect mysql workbench to remote database

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a remote mysql database on mydomain.com power by goDaddy and have a database name "arsenal101" with several tables and I have assigned the user "arsenal101" with password "22216888" with full privilege to that database.

In my local MySQl workbench in Macbook, I try connecting my MySQL workbench to that remote database.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

The hostname I enter mydomain.com
The username is arsenal101
The password is 22216888
The default schema is blank.

After I pressed test connection, an error message showed up " Failed to Connect to MySQL at mydomain.com: 3306 with user arsenal101
access denied for user arsenal101@xxxxxxx   (using password Yes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if GoDaddy allows you to do a remote connection to the database because a lot of hosting companies don't allow that. Their MySQL has to be configured to receive external connections.

Answer (score 0):

According to here: https://in.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978

If you want to connect remotely to a database, you must enable Direct Database Access when setting it up1 — you cannot enable it later.